# Jquery parse integer in a sentence/line that is not part of the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I want to do jQuery integer and string parsing. The user will just input string in the textarea.

1.) First get the integer from sentence that is not part of a string.

```
input           integer output   text output     
1 7-up            1                 7-up
3 coke            3                 coke
8 popcorn         8                 popcorn
6cups 5           5                 6cups
```

With this setup i can already parse the integer per line input by the user.
So how I can achieve the goals?

Comment: Would be nice to know more about your problem because it is hard to understand, and help. What are the possibilities? What the user insert first? There can be spaces in the user's input? Can you post the HTML of your form?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the amount of information that you posted, it is hard to help but if you have a HTML like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea>1 7-up</textarea>
    <textarea>3 coke</textarea>
    <textarea>8 popcorn</textarea>
    <textarea>6cups 5</textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

This should be your JavaScript:

```
var parsed = $('textarea').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).toArray().reduce(function(result, input, input_index) {
  if(result === false) return;

  var value = input.match(/\b(\d+)\b/);
  if(value === null) {
    alert('Unable to find the value/digit from input: ' + (input_index + 1));
    return false;
  }

  result.push({
    text: input.replace(value[0], '').replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, ''),
    number: value[0]
  });

  return result;
}, []);

console.log(parsed);
/*
[
  {
    "text": "7-up",
    "number": "1"
  },
  {
    "text": "coke",
    "number": "3"
  },
  {
    "text": "popcorn",
    "number": "8"
  },
  {
    "text": "6cups",
    "number": "5"
  }
]
*/
```